# Symfony locale on homepage issue

Tags: symfony4, symfony-routing

my website url's should be: 
http://www.example.com/nl 
http://www.example.com/en

I set it this way
in my config/routes.yml

```
homepage:
    resource: '@ProjectBaseBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
    prefix: /{_locale}
```

The issue persist when i visit

http://www.example.com/ 
Without a language.
When this happens i got a 404

How to handle it the correct way?

I googled arround, created extra route on the / etc..
The meaning is when they visit the unlocalized adress they get a redirect to the localized homepage.

Tips ?

Comment: Hello did you have solved it? I'm facing the same issue.